# Programmatically determine memory usage of each tab in firefox?

Tags: firefox, memory-management, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Looking to write a `firefox addon` so will have access to privilaged api. I've looked through the `addon-sdk`, particallarly [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Track_tabs), but dont see an easy way to access, have I missed something?

I noticed [about:addons-memory](https://github.com/nmaier/about-addons-memory) which shows memory usage per addon which is not quite what I'm after.

Comment: about:memory seems to have that information, more or less. so maybe it's possible to use the same APIs that it uses to get the info for the current tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to start with [`nsIMemoryReporterManager`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e0cb32a0b1aa/xpcom/base/nsIMemoryReporter.idl#l209)

The memory reporter manager recently gained a `.sizeOfTab()` method, which might be helpful, but see the caveats about underestimating memory usage.

Alternatively, you could parse the reports yourself using (`.getReports()`) and mapping the `explict/window-objects/top(..., id=...)` branches to tabs. The id stuff relates to the [inner or outer window id](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/interfaces/base/nsIDOMWindowUtils.idl#1256), I forget which one.